# Can I read a value of Jenkins plugin (i.e. GitHub repo url) property, which is already set in UI, to use it in pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, github, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I know how to **set** these properties in pipeline Groovy script, i.e. for GitHub plugin:

```
properties([
   $class: 'GithubProjectProperty',
   displayName: '',
   projectUrlStr: 'https://gitlab.com/group/project/'
])
```

But is it possible to **read** this value (url) inside the Jenkins pipeline script, if it was previously set in pipeline UI config manually (GitHub project -> Project url)? To use further somewhat like variables/parameters:

```
echo projectUrlStr
```

Using params.projectUrlStr or env.projectUrlStr is not working.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the GIT_URL environment variable:

`env.GIT_URL`

Comment: Hi, this returns null unfortunately.

Comment: env.GIT_URL is not value of "URL for the GitHub hosted project"